# Is statusbar mandatory in iphone Application

Tags: iphone, uistatusbar

Is status bar compulsory in iPhone App?

Will Apple reject my application if I hide status bar in all the screen of my iPhone Application?

Thanks.

Comment: Many apps do not show the status bar. Why do you think they would reject yours based on that?

Comment: I doubted it because, I did not get any iOS App (except games) without  status bar. And, I wasn't able to find any apple doc related to it. Thanks for answer, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the status bar is NOT mandatory in your app and it won't get rejected.

There are tons of apps that do not utilize the status bar. Also, there are a ton of apps that show and hide it throughout the app depending on the need for it. You are safe if you decide to not use it, or do use it or only use it sometimes throughout your app.

Answer (score 5):

Even though it is not necessary but you should be very judicious when to show or hide it..

For Eg. When playing a game it is ok to hide the status bar since the entire attention of the user is on the game.. where as if it is normal app like chatting and similar apps the person would like to check the time or his network status to see if data connectivity is available , so you should avoid hiding the bar in such cases...

Keeping in mind the amount of apps available on the app store... you never know what can miff off the user..

Answer (score 2):

No, the status bar is NOt mandatory in any App of Apple. Apple won't reject any App because of status bar hidden.

Answer (score 0):

status bar is not compulsory but hiding it indefinitely in some kind of applications (non games and non full graphics) can cause App store rejections.

From [Apple HIG](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-bars/status-bars/)

> Avoid permanently hiding the status bar. Without a status bar, people must leave your app to check the time or see if they have a Wi-Fi connection. Let people redisplay a hidden status bar by using a simple, discoverable gesture. When browsing full-screen photos in the Photos app, a single tap shows the status bar again.

Other real life [experiences](https://github.com/calimarkus/JDStatusBarNotification/issues/30)